# Can a collapse of the AMOC lead to suboxic conditions?

Tags: climate-change, ocean-currents, thermohaline-circulation

For a couple of years The Atlantic meridional overturning circulation AMOC has been under observation. There have been examples in the past, when sudden state changes of it lead to short term and hefty cooling on the northern hemisphere (Younger Dryas).

Now there may be immediate danger of this happening in the coming decades:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-39810-w

Pop science:
https://phys.org/news/2023-07-gloomy-climate-scientists-collapse-atlantic.html

Quite of few papers deal with possible implications on regional and global circulation patterns. My question is, as the AMOC is one of the main drivers of the global ocean heat exchange, could a collapse lead to a (more) stable layering, and thus possibly to suboxic conditions in parts of the great ocean basins?

Comment: Try this paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41558-022-01380-y maybe you can access this one :)

Comment: Have no acess, but looking up the article on pop science phys.org I found "A collapse [of AMOC] would profoundly alter [..] the world's oceans. [..] fresher at depth, deplete them of oxygen, and starve the upper ocean of the upwelling [..]". So, yeah, that's certainly worth an anwser.

Answer (score 1):

To cite Bryam Orihuela-Pinto et al. You will see that the collaps of the amoc changes Wind pattern and the heat structure of the oceans. These two factors, along with salinity, are the most important factors responsible for ocean upheaval. In the absence of overturning, this leads to strong accumulations of nutrient-rich deep waters, which are then subject to upwelling due to the inflow of warm waters. This boosts primary production extremely strongly, which in turn leads to increased respiration. Oxygen is consumed during respiration, resulting in suboxic conditions.

> Climate projections suggest a weakening or collapse of the Atlantic Meridional Overturning Circulation (AMOC) under global warming, with evidence that a slowdown is already underway. This could have significant ramifications for Atlantic Ocean heat transport, Arctic sea ice extent and regional North Atlantic climate. However, the potential for far-reaching effects, such as teleconnections to adjacent basins and into the Southern Hemisphere, remains unclear. Here, using a global climate model we show that AMOC collapse can accelerate the Pacific trade winds and Walker circulation by leaving an excess of heat in the tropical South Atlantic. This tropical warming drives anomalous atmospheric convection, resulting in enhanced subsidence over the east Pacific and a strengthened Walker circulation and trade winds. Further teleconnections include weakening of the Indian and South Atlantic subtropical highs and deepening of the Amundsen Sea Low. These findings have important implications for understanding the global climate response to ongoing greenhouse gas increases.